# How to merge two datasets if one is of type factor and the other is of type date in R?

Tags: r, date, merge

I am making use of the edgar package to look up specific information about companies that are listed in the U.S. SEC system. I need to create a dataset with all companies. For the companies that have the 10-k report type, the dataset is created automatically by the package, using the following code:

```
threeM <- searchFilings(cik.no = "66740", form.type = "10-K", filing.year = c(1996:2018), word.list)
```

```
write.csv(threeM, "threeM").
```

For companies that do not have the 10-k, datasets are not created automatically, so I built them manually by the following code:

```
 electrolux <- data.frame(cik = "813810",
                         company.name = "AB electrolux",
                         form.type = "NA",
                         date.filed = "NA",
                         nword.hits = "NA"
                         )
```

I need to create a dataset that includes all the companies, merging them together. So, I chose to merge the datasets of companies that start with the letter A and have the 10-k reports and put them together with the dataset that encompasses all the companies that start with the letter A, but do not have the 10-k report.

So I used the command:

```
full_join(A1, A2)
```

But the following answer came up:

```
Can't join on `x$date.filed` x `y$date.filed` because of incompatible types. ℹ `x$date.filed` is of type <date>>. ℹ `y$date.filed` is of type <factor<279f2>>>.
```

I already tried to transform one of the dataframes into type date, but the columns got scrambled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dplyr` joins require data to be of same type. Try creating the dataframe as :

```
electrolux <- data.frame(cik = "813810",
                         company.name = "AB electrolux",
                         form.type = NA_character_,
                         date.filed = as.Date(NA),
                         nword.hits = NA_real_, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```